# ArcGIS REST API test performance

Tags: arcgis-server, performance, arcgis-rest-api, rest

I need to test the performance of the ArcGIS REST API (Version: 10.51) on the map services I have created. The tester within our team is using *swagger* but it is not implemented in the ArcGIS REST API.

Are there any ESRI tools (external or REST API) to check the performance of the ArcGIS REST API? Where should I look out for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I managed to find the solution to that. ESRI does not provide testing tools bu it provides monitoring tools (if anyone interested to monitor instead). Details on [this link](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.5/administer/linux/about-server-statistics.htm).

In order to test the performance of the ArcGIS REST API I used the [blazemeter website](http://www.blazemeter.com) and created a call by setting the amount of users and the testing time. Essentially this is a JMeter. Token from the blazemeter account should be added on the call. Token also from the REST API should be added.

Details on Blazemeter docs in [this link](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us).